# Python modbus como server

Tags: python

¿Alguien sabe como modificar este fichero de Python para que sea servidor en lugar de cliente?

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('127.0.0.1')
client.write_coil(1, True)
result = client.read_coils(1,1)
print result.bits[0]
client.close()
```

Necesito que sea servidor pero no manejo esas librería bien.

Comment: Para que se vea bien el código `python` selecciona el texto y luego pulsa el botón <kbd>{}</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacer uso de [`StartTcpServer`](http://pythonhosted.org/pymodbus/library/async-server.html#pymodbus.server.async.StartTcpServer) y no de `ModbusTcpClient`.

Mira el ejemplo del servidor que [usan aquí](http://pythonhosted.org/pymodbus/examples/asynchronous-server.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer

from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# initialize your data store
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# run the server
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
StartTcpServer(context)
```

Enlaces a recursos que te pueden ser de interés:

- Scraper: http://pythonhosted.org/pymodbus/examples/modbus-scraper.html
- Simulador: http://pythonhosted.org/pymodbus/examples/modbus-simulator.html

El simulador usa la salida del scraper para crear un servidor con los datos de un servidor real al que se le ha hecho scraping.

Comment: El problema es adaptarlo a mi fichero. Además no entiendo algunas partes del ejemplo como la parte del loggin. Me gustaría algo más sencillo para escuchar simplemente como server.

Comment: Lo del `logging` no tiene nada que ver con `pymodbus`, puedes omitirlo. Es una clase que te ofrece `python` para facilitar la [depuración de aplicaciones](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html). Edito mi respuesta para evitarte confusiones.

Comment: cuando actua el fichero como server....¿no hace falta ponerle la IP del PLC? Me refiero que si no hay que decirle en ningún lado por que IP se conecta al cliente

Comment: No, no es necesario porque el servidor va a ser tu propio equipo, así que en el cliente puedes poner la IP del equipo donde ejecutas el servidor, o bien poner `127.0.0.1` (localhost) si ejecutas el cliente desde el mismo equipo que el servidor.

Comment: perdona que insista con el tema pero para hacer un programa muy simple que escriba por pantalla si me conecta con los registros del PLC ¿Como sería? Por que el trozo anterior no me imprime ninguna traza de conexión establecida o registros leidos....

Comment: El código anterior sólo crear un servidor que se queda a la espera de conexiones de clientes. Como hemos quitado el código de depuración no aparecerá nada por pantalla. Si quieres que aparezca algo por pantalla habrá que agregar de nuevo el código que habilita la depuración (`logging`).

Comment: Por favor ¿te importa poner el código completo para probar ahora mismo?

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente error al ejecutar el código:

from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer 

no module named twisted

Comment: Como con cualquier otro módulo, debes ejecutar `pip install twisted` para que se instale (cuando instalaste `pymodbus` debiste usar `pip install pymodbus`, ¿me equivoco?). Si hubieras usado ese comando habrías visto esta línea para satisfacer las dependencias: `Downloading/unpacking twisted>=12.2.0 (from pymodbus)`

Comment: ¿Algún problema usando `pip`? ¿Llegaste a echarlo a andar?